# Why do I get this syntax error about T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I have a function that I use to display the items in the user's shopping cart in a table:

```
function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM menu WHERE quantity > 0');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo"Sorry, There is no products to display.";
    }
    else {
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
            echo '<p>''<table>''<tr>''<td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td>''<td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td>''<td>$'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td>''<td>''<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td></tr></table></p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use that code, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`, expecting `,` or `;` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\cart.php` on line 37

Line 37 is this line:

```
echo '<p>''<table>''<tr>''<td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td>''<td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td>''<td>$'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td>''<td>''<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td></tr></table></p>';
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

PHP, unlike some other languages, does not automatically concatenate consecutive string literals. You'll have to either explicitly concatenate:

```
echo 'a' . 'b' . 'c' . $someVar . 'd';
```

Or use commas:

```
echo 'a', 'b', 'c', $someVar, 'd';
```

Or just join the literals yourself:

```
echo 'abc' . $someVar . 'd';
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have the little '' in there. IE:

```
<p>''<table>''<tr>''<td>
```

change it to...

```
<p><table><tr><td>
```

And everywhere else that you have a '' like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo '<p><table><tr><td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td><td>$'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td><td><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td></tr></table></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Things like this `'<p>''<table>'` are no good. Why don't you put them all into one `'<p><table>'` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<p><table><tr><td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td>
<td>'$.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td>
<td><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr></table></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to write like this in while loop

echo '<p><table><tr><td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td><td>$'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td><td><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td></tr></table></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
echo'<p><table><tr><td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['description'].'</td><td>'.$number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'</td><td><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add To Cart</a></td></tr></table></p>';
```

Simple friend.accept answer if it is works for you.
You also done a wrong at

```
<td>'.$number_format($get_row['price'],2).'</td>//you coded like <td>$'.number_format()...
```